# How Call for a BAT script in UNC folder and avoid Win32Exception (0x80004005): The operation was canceled by the user

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file, scripting

I use VS 2017 Community, Windows Forms app, and I try call to BAT script (in UNC folder):

```
Process.Start(@"\\sharefolder\editHosts.bat");
```

Sometimes I get the error:

> ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The operation was canceled by the user
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

I have already checked the following things:

- The folder exists
- The user has rights to the folder (can open it in Explorer)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check event viewer to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Group policy may prevent execution on UNC paths. I think this will fail silently unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure your UNC path is correct? `\\sharefolder` should read `\\servername\sharefolder\...` instead. Also: can you execute the batch file manually without error?

Comment: do you run it using VS as admin?

Comment: app not run as admin